# Converting array of objects to objects of array having similar field value

Tags: arrays, object

```
var array = [{"name":"Vani","Id":"1"},{"name":"Random","Id":"1"},{"name":"Random1","Id":"2"},{"name":"Random2","Id":"2"}];
```

Convert to following object using reduce based on unique field value id:

```
var obj = {"1":[{"name":"Vani","Id":"1"},{"name":"Random","Id":"1"}],"2":[{"name":"Random1","Id":"2"},{"name":"Random2","Id":"2"}]}
```

Comment: Basically, you are looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to get the desired output:

```js
const data = [{"name":"Vani","Id":"1"},{"name":"Random","Id":"1"},{"name":"Random1","Id":"2"},{"name":"Random2","Id":"2"}];

const result = data.reduce((r, c) => {
  r[c.Id] = r[c.Id] || [];
  r[c.Id].push(c);
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```